# how to convert the type of array to double in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, types

Hello there I'm trying to change the type of string array contain numbers like {12.3 , 33.7 , ...}
and I want to convert the type of this array into Double in c#

Answer (score 5):

LINQ `Select` is used to transform objects from one form to another. `double.Parse` is used to parse `string` values into `double` values. You can combine them to:

```
double[] doubles = strings.Select(double.Parse).ToArray();
```

you can also use what is called lambda syntax

```
double[] doubles = strings.Select(s => double.Parse(s)).ToArray();
```

You should definitely get acquainted with LINQ technology. Consider great collection of [101 LINQ Samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b) as a learning tutorial

Answer (score 3):

```
var doubleArray = Array.ConvertAll(stringArray, input => double.Parse(input));
```

Comment: +1 for using **.net 2.0** feature